# Entity Framework Saving User when record is Modified

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

When a Record gets updated in my Database, I need to be able to save who edited it.

Currently in my Repository I do this

```
pt.ModifiedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

There has to be a better way of doing this or is this only method?

Comment: If your application don't login to database by user login (impersonation) the only thing that you can is to set ModifiedBy property in your application.

Comment: combine both answers... dont tightly couple and put a nice feature in your Repository Base class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO the best option is to handle all the auditing in one place - your unit of work (`DbContext`). This is easily achieved by having all of your Poco objects implement a common interface, such as IEntity.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        //you may need this line depending on your exact configuration
        //ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        foreach (DbEntityEntry o in GetChangedEntries())
        {
            IEntity entity = o.Entity as IEntity;
            entity.ModifiedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> GetChangedEntries()
    {
        return new List<DbEntityEntry>(
            from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
            where e.State != System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged
            select e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

By using `HttpContext.Current.User` you're tightly coupling your `DbContext` with `HttpContext` which is not a good idea in case you'll expose your `DbContext` to a non-web environment (UnitTesting, WCF, WPF etc).

You can use **`System.Security.Principal.IIdentity`** instead, just like exposed in **ASP.NET** (`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`), **WCF** (`System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity`) and **Thread** (`Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`).

Then, have your `DbContext` accept `IIdentity` in its constructor, and whenever the context initialized pass the appropriate `IIdentity` (from your current context).

For example (based on @qujck answer):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IIdentity _identity;

    public DbContext(IIdentity identity)
    {
          this._identity = identity;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        //you may need this line depending on your exact configuration
        //ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        foreach (DbEntityEntry o in GetChangedEntries())
        {
            IEntity entity = o.Entity as IEntity;
            entity.ModifiedBy = this._identity.Name;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}

// Usage (ASP.NET):
var context = new DbContext(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
```

Comment: Good advice on separation of concerns